# Not receiving Firebase reset password email

Tags: email, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Im using the Console interface > Authentication > Users.

I created several email/password based users (using the console web UI), and then selected the action to "reset password" to send a reset password email for several users.

I see a "Password Reset email was sent" popup on screen, but I never receive the email, I thought it might be in SPAM folder, but no. and I tried different email addresses with different email providers including Gmail. Emails are never received.

Any idea? again... I created the users using the console UI ("ADD USER" button) in the Firebase System.

[image]

Comment: nevermind, it took like 40 minutes for Firebase to send all the emails. insane.

Comment: Probably because your project is new. In practice I've gotten password reset emails rather quickly.

Comment: I get them almost instantly 95% of the time.

Comment: There have been some reports of email delivery delays. You can track the status for this here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/17005

Comment: It took 30 minutes for me. OMG How the client will accept this.

Comment: I waited for two hours, when it finally came, it said link has expired and I should request a new one.

Comment: Still seeing this issue, that's really bad.

Comment: It's 2022 and this problem still exists. Come on Firebase.

Comment: same here.. I dont receive any messages in email at all